# IE6 Jquery Namespace problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

The following code works in all browsers apart from IE6...

```
var mylib =
{
    selectStyle :
    {
        init : function()
        {
            $('#select-box1').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
        }
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
mylib.selectStyle.init();
</script>
```

The error states 'mylib' is undefined

Can someone please help otherwise I will have to spend alot of time redoing a lot more code than this.

Many thanks,
C

Comment: A suggestion: you should put your open brackets in the same line. Or you might encounter some problems (with JavaScript), there are some issues regarding the `return { ... };` when the bracket is in a new line. There might be others.

Comment: Whilst I agree with the comments about the placement of `{` and `;`, the above should work in IE6, and does for me, as long as I put the `mylib` assignment in a `<script>` block too (obviously it won't do anything as HTML). I think your problem is in code you're not showing us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a semicolon at the end of the definition of mylib.

```
var mylib = { ... };
```

When declaring anything in `var something = ...;` always add a semicolon at the end.

Thank you IE, you are so wonderful, reminding us to put semicolons. (Sarcasm? maybe...)

**Edit:** The semicolon is not a recommendation, IE considers it an error if you don't put it after closing curly brackets, so if you declare  a function in a var, put the semicolon too.

`var myFunc = function(){ .... };`.

But if you declare a function in the namespace, you don't need to add the semicolon.

`function doSomething(){ ... }` <-- no semicolon.